# Why is my error saying that the attribute I am trying to call does not exist?

Tags: python, attributes, attributeerror, dice

First off, I am a complete beginner and I am sorry for asking this basic question but I've just been stuck on it. I am trying to create a dice roller that will generate the sum of two six-sided dice (so basically it will generate a number between 2-12).
This is my code:

```
def dice(): 
    import random
    first = random.randint(1, 6)
    second = random.randint(1, 6)
    roll = first + second
```

However, when I call `< dice.roll >` , I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'dice' has no attribute 'roll'
```

Why is it saying that my module 'dice' has no attribute 'roll' when I did define roll in the last line of my code? I feel like there's a simple reason for this but I just can't recall it.

Comment: you seem to be trying to interact with dice like its a class, but its a function. the simplest way to resolve this is change this line `roll = first + second` to `return first + second` and then use it as `dice()`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a local variable in a function, return the result instead.

Also, I recommend you to put imports at the top of the file and not in function.

```py
import random
def dice():
    first = random.randint(1, 6)
    second = random.randint(1, 6)
    roll = first + second
    return roll
```

```py
dice1 = dice()
```

Example Output

```
5
```

Answer (score 0):

`dice` is not a class, so you cannot retrieve the variable from the function that way without defining a variable called `dice.roll`. What you could do, is use the `global` keyword to make the scope of the variable to be accessible outside of the function:

```
import random
def dice(): 
    global roll
    first = random.randint(1, 6)
    second = random.randint(1, 6)
    roll = first + second 

print(roll)
```

If you do want to call the function using that syntax, you could do:

```
import random
def dice(): 
    first = random.randint(1, 6)
    second = random.randint(1, 6)
    dice.roll = first + second 

dice()
print(dice.roll)
```

You could also simply return `roll`:

```
import random
def dice(): 
    first = random.randint(1, 6)
    second = random.randint(1, 6)
    roll = first + second
    return roll 

dice()
```

Another side note, try to keep the imports at the top. (Look at PEP 8)

```
import random
def dice(): 
    first = random.randint(1, 6)
    second = random.randint(1, 6)
    roll = first + second
    return roll 

dice()
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a function. Functions can only be run using their names like `dice()`. But your function doesn’t actually return anything.

You could do `return roll` at the last line. Or `return first+second`.

So like this

```
def dice(): 
    import random
    first = random.randint(1, 6)
    second = random.randint(1, 6)
    roll = first + second
    return roll
```

Then you could try `print(dice())`.

Or if you wanted to create a dice object with a roll function. You would first need to create a dice class and define a roll function within the dice class.

An example would be like this

```
import random

class Dice():
    def __init__(self, dice = 1):
        self.dice = dice
        self.result = 0

    def roll(self):
        for i in self.dice:
            self.result += random.randint(1, 6)
    
    def get_result(self):
        print(self.result)
```

Then you can dynamically create more dice,

You can start like this,

```
dice = Dice(2) #creates dice object with 2 dice
dice.roll() #will roll the 2 dice and store the result in roll
dice.get_result() #will print the result
```

You could also create it like this

```
import random

class Dice():
    def __init__(self, dice = 1):
        self.dice = dice
        self.result = 0

    def roll(self):
        for i in self.dice:
            self.result += random.randint(1, 6)
        print(self.result)
```

Then you can run it like this,

```
dice = Dice(2) #creates dice object with 2 dice
dice.roll() #will roll the 2 dice and print the result
```